# jQuery UI Dialog Open causing a display compatibility issue in IE9

Tags: cross-browser, internet-explorer-9, jquery-ui-dialog

There is a jquery-ui dialog that needs to be opened on a page load. The relevant code is in two files.

```
**FileA**
$(function()
{
   //some initialization code here

    $("#date-range-dialog").dialog({
        modal: true, 
        autoOpen: false, 
        buttons: 
        {
            "Ok": function() 
            {
               //some code here
            }
        }
    });
});

**FileB**
$(function()
{
   //some code

   $('#date-range-dialog').dialog('open');
});
```

This works fine with Chrome and Firefox. But with IE9, the open dialog event/statement is causing the browser to switch the display to the Compatibility View.

The mark-up for the dialog is:

```
<div id="date-range-dialog" title="Date Range">
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">From</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" id="dt-from" class="input-small" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">To</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" id="dt-to" class="input-small" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The application is using Twitter Bootstrap 2.0.4, jQuery 1.8.3, jQuery UI 1.9.2.
There is no manual CSS at the moment.

A strange observation is that if the statement to open the dialog is commented out, it works in IE9 too. If there is button that calls this statement, everything is fine:

```
$(".date-range").click(function()
{
    $("#date-range-dialog").dialog("open");
});
```

So, the problem occurs only when the dialog is trying to be opened directly within `$(function(){});`

I have tried placing the dialog open statement in the `$(window).load()` event too. It still fails in IE9.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try putting the jQuery from file B into a `$(document).ready({});` clause?  I'd guess that perhaps IE is running the code from file B before it has done its initialisation in file A.  That would explain why it works in your click function but not your file B function.

Comment: `$(document).ready({})` and `$(function(){})` are equivalent functions.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.  Still I would suggest it is a loading order issue.  Maybe put a timeout on the file B function?